# How to configure the Neo4j repository with Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.0?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I tried to upgrade from the 3.3.2 to the 3.4.0 version of spring data neo4j on search.maven.org but the build now gives the following exception:

```
AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
```

The application works just fine in 3.3.2.

Here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = { "it.data.neo4j.repository" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "it.data.neo4j.service" })
public class Neo4JRepositoryConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4JRepositoryConfiguration.class);

  public static final String URL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";
  public static final String LOGIN = "neo4j";
  public static final String PASSWORD = "xxxx";

  Neo4JRepositoryConfiguration() {
    setBasePackage("it.data.neo4j.domain");
  }

  @Bean
  GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase(URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
  }

  @Autowired
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

  @Override
  public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager(
      GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(
        new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject()),
        new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService).getObject());
  }

}
```

The dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a conflicting class path dependencies with spring-data-commons.jar

Make sure all jars on the class path are using the same version of spring-data-commons.

In my case I had 2 jars referencing both spring-data-commons.jar 1.10 and 1.11 which caused the issue.

Comment: I gave up upgrading to 4.0 as it does not yet support embedded graph services. This should come in 4.1. And it made my question too broad. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: By the way, I have only one spring-data-commons the 1.10.2.RELEASE seen in a mvn dependency:tree command.

Comment: Upgrading spring-data-commons to 1.11.0.RELEASE seems to have solved that issue. However I now have another one: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@5deae1b7' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.

Comment: I'm now back to spring-data-commons 1.10.2.RELEASE as it fails to load the context.

Comment: @Stephane Eybert I wouldn't manually upgrade the  spring-data-commons dependency by itself. Sounds like you could have other dependencies that are using an older version of a jar. I just got on 4.0 and it works "fine" for basic CRUD functionality. You should turn on more verbose debug logging for 'org.neo4j' package path to see what the exception is exactly (I can't see the exception)

Comment: Just for the record, I removed the spring-data-commons dependency on SDN 3.3.2 and the build gave me the following exception: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentPropertyAccessor I shall now see if I get luckier with SDN 4.0.

Comment: Here is the logging I now have         Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.neo4j");
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
and         Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.springframework.data.neo4j");
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
Is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Stephane Eybert normally configured via log4j.xml (or log4j.properties) 'enable' debug logging for 'org.neo4j' package path like so:       <logger name="org.neo4j">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger> but I suppose you can programmatically do it as well. Yea I don't think you should manually remove/change dependencies that is just asking for trouble. You should only change the dependency versions in your pom file and then (after a clean + build) analyze what dependencies have a conflict.

Comment: I had configured the logging in a java bean as you can see in my above comment. I can't say I then have seen more in the log though. Regarding the dependencies, I only manage them in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Does your package `it.data.neo4j.repository` contain both JPA and Neo4j repositories?  If so you may need to segregate them into separate packages.

Additionally, Spring Data Neo4j version 4 is a major shift from the previous versions and a bit of code migration is involved, it is possible your actual application code needs to be adjusted to be compatible with SDN4:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#migration

Comment: Yes, the JPA code is in its own package and so is the Neo4j code. The application works just fine in 3.3.2 but I was trying to upgrade it.

Comment: In case my previous comment was not that clear, the JPA sits in one package, and the Neo4j sits in another one. They have never shared a package.