# Issue with Spring Data JPA when upgrading to 1.9.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am having a JPA web application with Java configuration. The dependencies of the application are added manually, means without using Spring boot.
Its Spring Data JPA version is 1.7.1.RELEASE. It is working fine now.

But when i upgraded the Spring Data JPA version to 1.9.0.RELEASE it shows following error:

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/shaheer/workspace/my-webapp/target/classes/com/sample/webapp/config/PersistenceConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:267)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.registerDefaultValues(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.doVisitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.doVisitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279)
    ... 24 more
```

Here is My JPA configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.sample.webapp.jpa.dao")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.webapp.jpa.entity");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return factory;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
public ResourceDatabasePopulator initDatabase(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db/hsql/insert-data.sql"));
    populator.populate(dataSource.getConnection());
    return populator;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
}
```

And my pom.xml is as follows

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <postgresql.driver.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgresql.driver.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.7</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.12</org.slf4j-version>
        <jackson-json.version>2.6.3</jackson-json.version>
        <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
        <jsp-api-version>2.2</jsp-api-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
        <junit-version>4.7</junit-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

            <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp-api-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring session -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SpringSecurity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database (H2) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.189</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC handle multipart file upload START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring MVC handle multipart file upload END -->

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Please provide your suggestions to solve my issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of your `spring-data-commons`, as seem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003334/1995130) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739127/1995130).

Comment: The issue was the spring-data-commons versions conflict. Thanks